# Reparenting a Qt widget

Tags: qt, widget, qsplitter

I have a `WidgetA` widget, which is an owner-drawn widget. It's currently placed in `QMainWindow`'s `QVBoxLayout`. After clicking a button, I'd like to "detach" `WidgetA` from this `QVBoxLayout`, insert `QSplitter` into this `QVBoxLayout` and "readd" `WidgetA` to this `QSplitter`. All this without destroying `WidgetA`, so it will preserve its drawing context, etc.

So, currently I have this (only one widget in a window):

[image: only one widget in a window]

I'd like to put a `QSplitter` between `WidgetA` and `QMainWindow`, and create a new widget, `WidgetB`, so I'd end up with:

[image: two widgets, split by QSplitter]

Later I'd like it to split even further, so both `WidgetA` and `WidgetB` would still allow themselves to be detached and placed in a new `QSplitter`, so it would be possible to create f.e. this hierarchy:

[image: three widgets, split by two QSplitters]

And, to be complete, one more step:

[image: four widgets, split by three QSplitters]

I'm not very experienced in Qt, so what I'm trying to do may seem pretty obvious, but I couldn't find how to "reparent" widgets. Is this possible in Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, see reparent example, may be it helps you:

```
//MyMainWindow.h
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSplitter>

class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
  MyWidget(QWidget* parent, int number)
    : QWidget(parent),
      m_number(number)
  {

  }

private:
  virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
  {
    QWidget::paintEvent(e);

    QPainter p(this);
    p.fillRect( rect(), Qt::red);
    p.drawText( rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(m_number) );
  }

private:
  int m_number;
};

class MyMainWindow: public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyMainWindow()
  {
    setFixedSize(300, 200);

    m_mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QHBoxLayout* buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    m_mainLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);

    m_button = new QPushButton("Button", this);
    buttonLayout->addWidget(m_button);

    connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonClickedOnce()));

    m_initWidget = new MyWidget(this, 1);
    m_mainLayout->addWidget(m_initWidget);
  }

private slots:
  void onButtonClickedOnce()
  {
    m_button->disconnect(this);

    m_mainLayout->removeWidget(m_initWidget);
    QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal, this);
    m_mainLayout->addWidget(splitter);

    splitter->addWidget(m_initWidget);
    MyWidget* newWidget = new MyWidget(splitter, 2);
    splitter->addWidget(newWidget);
  }

private:
  QVBoxLayout* m_mainLayout;
  QWidget* m_initWidget;
  QPushButton* m_button;
};

//main.cpp

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyMainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you operate with widget which is part of layout, then you need to use appropriate methods of QLayout (parent of QVBoxLayout) to detach the item from layout:

QLayout::removeWidget (removeItem if it is not widget, but spacer item or another layout)
QLayout::addWidget (addItem --/--)

Btw: even when widget moves between layouts, its parent may even stay same. I guess you have no need to call QWidget::setParent() as the calls of addWidget/removeWidget will do all work for you.